Polynomial Expansion of a Function
Say I have a function $f(x)$ defined on $[-1,1]$, I can expand it (given some more information) using the traditional Fourier series, which uses $e^{inx}$ as the basis function, or the Fourier-Legendre expansion, which uses the Legendre polynomials as the basis functions. My question is, if we expand both in terms of polynomials, by expanding $e^{inx}$ using the Taylor series, as the order of both tends to infinity, will the coefficients be the same in both expansions? (Given that the expansion in both cases converges uniformly).
My intuition would be yes since they both converge to the same function, but I wanted a confirmation of this hypothesis.
